# Sinatra: Hot Code Pushes In Production?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger, unicorn

When I push new code from my Sinatra application to my production server, I am currently triggering a restart of passenger by touching `tmp/restart.txt`, which loads the new changes.  The problem is that the site is essentially down for about 10 seconds during this process.

How can I setup my server so that I can completely avoid any downtime?

That is, I want the application to keep serving the old version of the code until the new code is completely loaded, and then to instantly switch to the new code.

Using shotgun or sinatra/reloader will not work here since this is a production environment.  Finally, if the answer depends on the application server, I'd be interested in how to do it with both unicorn and passenger.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app ? With passenger, just touch tmp/restart.txt and Passenger will restart the app on the next request.

Comment: @hdgarrood, I think my OP was not clear, or my understanding of what's going on is not entirely clear regarding Passenger/nginx, but what you described is in fact what I am currently doing.  But that next request you refer to takes 10 seconds to complete

Comment: @Jonah In that case I probably can't help ;) how long does it take to start the sinatra app standalone? Is it also 10 seconds?

Comment: @hdgarrood yeah I think the time is about the same

Comment: Well I hope someone answers this because I'd also like to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is rolling restarts. Phusion Passenger Enterprise supports this: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRollingRestarts

Comment: This is precisely what I want, ty